# Simplify switch statement

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

There are 3 boolean variables (var1, var2, var3)
if one of them is true (for each I need to do my own action) or if two of them are true (perform a special action) + default if none of the conditions were met

I tried this but it doesn't work very well

```
switch (true) {
  case (var1 || var2) && (var2 || var3):
    console.log('multi');
    break
  case var1:
    console.log('var1');
    break
  case var2:
    console.log('var2');
    break
  case var3:
    console.log('var3');
    break
  default:
    console.log('default')
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't work very well." Can you give some example inputs with expected output and the output you're currently getting? See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
switch (true) {
  case (var1 && var2) || (var1 && var3) || (var2 && var3):
    console.log('multi');
    break
  case var1:
    console.log('var1');
    break
  case var2:
    console.log('var2');
    break
  case var3:
    console.log('var3');
    break
  default:
    console.log('default')
 }
```

Comment: Are there any options to simplify this? (var1 && var2) || (var1 && var3) || (var2 && var3)

Comment: if ((var1 + var2+ var3) === 2)

Answer (score 2):

Encode it in a simple truth table

| var1 | var2 | var3 | **result** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| false | false | false | **default** |
| false | false | true | **var3** |
| false | true | false | **var2** |
| false | true | true | **multi** |
| true | false | false | **var1** |
| true | false | true | **multi** |
| true | true | false | **multi** |
| true | true | true | **multi** |

And now you can very easily do the same in code, then attach different handlers for the different conditions. The whole logic becomes a very simple lookup:

```js
//sample handlers for the different conditions
function defaultHandler() { console.log("default"); }
function var1Handler()    { console.log("var1");    }
function var2Handler()    { console.log("var2");    }
function var3Handler()    { console.log("var3");    }
function multiHandler()   { console.log("multi");   }

//initialise a table
const table = {true: {true: {}, false: {}}, false: {true: {}, false: {}}}

//fill it with values
table[false][false][false] = defaultHandler
table[false][false][true ] = var3Handler
table[false][true ][false] = var2Handler
table[false][true ][true ] = multiHandler
table[true ][false][false] = var1Handler
table[true ][false][true ] = multiHandler
table[true ][true ][false] = multiHandler
table[true ][true ][true ] = multiHandler

//simple resolver that takes the values and does the lookup
function resolve(var1, var2, var3) {
  return table[var1][var2][var3]();
}

resolve(false, false, false); // default
resolve(true , false, false); // var1
resolve(false, true , false); // var2
resolve(false, false, true ); // var3
resolve(true , true , false); // multi
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. But does it actually simplify OP's switch statement?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner yes. No need to do any conditional logic at all, once the permutations are all encoded in a table, it's absolutely clear what does what. I actually wasn't sure if OP wants something different to happen if all three are `true` but now it's trivial to change it, if needed, without having to add a different boolean condition and making sure it doesn't overlap and is not shadowed by anything. Furthermore, reading the code leaves no doubt what happens under any specific circumstance. It's simpler because there is nothing to really think about here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `(var1 || var2) && (var2 || var3)` succeeds if var2 is true and neither var1 nor var3 is true.

You could replace `(var1 || var2) && (var2 || var3)` with `((var1 && (var 2 || var 3)) || (var2 && var3))`

@EVeras solution would also work.

Answer (score 0):

`true` can be coerced to `1` and `false` can be coerced to `0`, so you can directly add up the booleans to see how many are true. Also, you can directly use `if` statements instead of switching on `true`.

```
if(var1 + var2 + var3 > 1){
    console.log('multi');
} else if(var1){
    console.log('var1');
} else if(var2){
    console.log('var2');
} else if(var3){
    console.log('var3');
} else {
    console.log('default');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can try this:

```
switch (true) {
     case !(var1 ^ var2 ^ var3):
       console.log('multi');
       break;
     case var1:
       console.log('var1');
       break;
     case var2:
       console.log('var2');
       break;
     case var3:
       console.log('var3');
       break;
     default:
       console.log('default');
   }
```

This is literally based on the 3-input XOR logic:

Here is image for clear understanding:
[image]

As you can notice whenever there are two `true`, the result is going to be false (hence `!`). But it fails in condition when all of them are `false` as shown in snapshot with red box. For that we will have to handle separately and then the solution will not remain elegant. So this solution is `NOT COMPLETELY CORRECT`.

Comment: A little explanation of ```!(var1 ^ var2 ^ var3)```?