# Javascript Large amount of conditions

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am building a quiz to determine what kind of skin you have based off 3 questions (oily, dry.. etc)

Is the best way to write the logic for this, something like the below or is there a more efficient way of doing this in terms of performance

```
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 1 && q3 == 1){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 1 && q3 == 2){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 1 && q3 == 3){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 1 && q3 == 4){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 2 && q3 == 1){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 2 && q3 == 2){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 2 && q3 == 3){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 3 && q3 == 1){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 3 && q3 == 2){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 4 && q3 == 1){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 4 && q3 == 2){ skinType = "DRY" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 2 && q3 == 4){ skinType = "COMBO" } else
if (q1 == 1 && q2 == 3 && q3 == 3){ skinType = "COMBO" } else
    ....etc
```

Comment: Encode it as a table like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68084392) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65586496) and hen you can use `skinType = table[q1][q2][q3]`. Although I don't think there is going to be a performance difference.

Comment: I think it's off-topic and should be on Code review

Comment: VLAZ suggestion has a big bonus: you can add new skin types to table programmatically. This make table far more usable from other components that can add skin types or remove them.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performace there's nothing faster than a simple condition, but not in terms of readability and code maintainance, which are also important in coding.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data. Try to find patterns or input combinations that determine exactly the target class (e.g. q1 ==1 && q2 == 1 is always "DRY") and eleminate the redundant lines.

Since many of your input combinations seem to result in the same class, i.e., DRY, COMBO, you could also try to build nested conditions similar to a [decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning).

```java
if (q1 == 1) {
    if (q2 == 1) {
        skinType = "DRY";
    } else if (q2 == 2) {
        if (q3 == 4) {
            skinType = "COMBO";
        } else {
            skinType = "DRY";
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

One more sophisticated option to build good decision trees is the [ID3 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Switch case statement for better performance("switch statement is faster in most cases when compared to if-else ").

Comment: Can you show code to your answer ? Please [edit] your answer :)